# Conjugating by orthogonal matrix inside determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose A is a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

Does it hold that

$$
\det(ABA^T) = \det(A(QBQ^T)A^T) 
$$

for all $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices $Q$ (i.e. $Q^{-1} = Q^T$)?

Comment: What’s the determinant of a product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider for instance $A =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $B =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $Q =\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, then

$$ ABA^T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = 1
$$

$$ AQBQ^TA^T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}
     \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = 2
$$